# Android Studio CharSequence Errors

Tags: android

I've been following a video wherein you will add two numbers using android studio...

txtResult.setText(result);
^
method TextView.setText(CharSequence) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Float cannot be converted to CharSequence)
method TextView.setText(int) is not applicable
(argument mismatch; Float cannot be converted to int)

Answer (score 1):

For `TextView`, there are two overloads of the `setText`:

- `setText(@StringRes int text)` - takes the string resource identifier as an argument
- `setText(CharSequence text)` - takes any `CharSequence` (most often, `String` as an argument)

The float resulting value that you computed in this calculator app is not string resource, so you should explicitly convert it to `CharSequence` to be able to put it into the `TextView`:

Kotlin:

```kotlin
txtResult.setText(res.toString())
```

Java:

```java
txtResult.setText(String.valueOf(res));
```